# Topological properties of the Join Operation of sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, lattice-orders

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Is there a topology on the set of all sub sigma algebras of $\mathcal{F}$, denoted by $\mathcal{F}^*$, that makes the join operation continuous?

More specifically: Let $A_n \rightarrow A$, for some index sets $A_n,A$ and $X_f$ with $f\in A, A_n$ a collection of real valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.

Is there a topology on $\mathcal{F}^*$ that gives
$$
\lim_n \bigvee_{f\in A_n} \sigma(X_f)= \sigma(X_f: f\in A)
$$
?

Comment: I have thought about it for all of one minute, but wouldn't the "Stone topology" given by subbasis $[A]=\{\mathcal F'\mid A\in \mathcal F' \}$, where $A\in \mathcal F$ work?

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that the operation (how you seem to want to define it) is not finitary. But the definition seems really awkward, I have trouble deciphering it. Why not dispense of the real variables and define it purely abstractly in terms of the subalgebras?

Comment: Oh, you might also want to add $\neg [A]=\{\mathcal F'\mid A\notin \mathcal F' \}$.

Comment: Actually, I want to consider only sigma algebras that are generated by random variables. The topology, I have in mind is related to Stinchcombe's "Baysian information topology", an iteration of the Hausdorff metric.

Comment: The topology I have described is very similar to the Vietoris topology (which for compact subsets of a metric space is induced by the Hausdorff metric), so it may or may not be relevant to your interest. I suggest you try considering the general case and then restricting the topology you obtain.